# Elevated processes ignore their privileges

Tags: windows, winapi, privileges

I don't quite understand how Windows process privilege system works. When I start my application as an administrator (i.e. elevated), according to Process Explorer, its `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` privilege exists but is disabled. Despite that, creating symlinks with `CreateSymbolicLink()` works fine.

My understanding was that an application needs to request a privilege using `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` before it does something that requires a given privilege (to change its status from "Disabled" to "Enabled"). Apparently that is not the case. Does that mean that elevated processes are exempt from privilege checks? I couldn't find any documentation on the topic.

Comment: `CreateSymbolicLink` internally call `RtlAcquirePrivilege` for enable `SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_PRIVILEGE` (35).

Comment: Then what's the point of those token APIs if winapi functions request privileges automatically?

Comment: we can enable or disable privilege, if it exist in token. we can not add new privilege, which not exist here. you have

Comment: @MichaelJamaica most APIs DON’T request privileges automatically, the caller is required to enable privileges beforehand. But few APIs do, including `CreateSymbolicLink()`.